# how to compare selected index of a combobox

Tags: java, combobox, actionlistener

Im trying to make a program that converts currencies. The program has two comboboxes on witch the user can choose between currencies. In a action performed method i want to check first if the index of both comboboxes are equal. so far the program works. Then, in in the same if statement i want to have another if statement that checks if the index of the combobox is 0. thats what i have problems wwith.

```
if (e.getSource() == firstCombobox)
    {
        firstCombobox.getSelectedIndex();
        indexFirstCombobox = firstCombobox.getSelectedIndex();
        firstCombobox.getSelectedItem();
        objectFirstCombobox = firstCombobox.getSelectedItem();

        secondCombobox.getSelectedIndex();
        indexSecondCombobox = secondCombobox.getSelectedIndex();
        //System.out.println("Picked: " + value1);
    }


if (e.getSource() == secondButton)
        {
            stringTextField = firstTextField.getText();
            integerTextField = Integer.parseInt(stringTextField);

            if (indexFirstCombobox == indexSecondCombobox)
            {
                if (indexFirstCombobox==0){
                    System.out.println(integerTextField + " Euros are " + integerTextField + " Euros");
```

It's an the following errror:Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because "this.indexFirstCombobox" is null
Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if your program doesn't enter through the "if" condition never assigns value to indexFirstCombobox, so you need to read the combo values and indexes by defaul outside the conditional if or check if nulls

```
indexFirstCombobox = firstCombobox.getSelectedIndex();
firstCombobox.getSelectedItem();
objectFirstCombobox = firstCombobox.getSelectedItem();        
indexSecondCombobox = secondCombobox.getSelectedIndex();
objectSecondCombobox = secondCombobox.getSelectedItem();

if (e.getSource() == firstCombobox)
    {
        //firstCombobox.getSelectedIndex();
        //indexFirstCombobox = firstCombobox.getSelectedIndex();
        //firstCombobox.getSelectedItem();
        //objectFirstCombobox = firstCombobox.getSelectedItem();

        //secondCombobox.getSelectedIndex();
        //indexSecondCombobox = secondCombobox.getSelectedIndex();
        //System.out.println("Picked: " + value1);
    }


if (e.getSource() == secondButton)
        {
            stringTextField = firstTextField.getText();
            integerTextField = Integer.parseInt(stringTextField);

            if (indexFirstCombobox == indexSecondCombobox)
            {
                if (indexFirstCombobox==0){
                    System.out.println(integerTextField + " Euros are " + integerTextField + " Euros");
```